# How to test an ajax form? With FormTester?

Tags: wicket

I have an ajax form which looks like

```
Form<Void>form=new Form<Void>("form");
add(form);
name=new TextField<String>("name");
form.add(name);
age=new TextField<Integer>("age");
form.add(age);
submit=new AjaxButton("submit") {
    @Override
    protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> form) {
        result.setDefaultModelObject(s);
        target.add(result);
    }
};
form.add(submit);
```

How do I test such a form, with `FormTester`, or in another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use FormTester, it will take care of simulating an Ajax request:

```
formTester.submit(button);
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, I can use FormTester, but I must do

```
wicketTester.executeAjaxEvent("form:submit", "click");
```

instead of

```
formTester.submit();
```

Also, because FormTester puts the values given with `.setValue()` in the post parameters, we can let BaseWicketTester.serializeFormRequest do this also, so we do not need FormTester:

```
wicketTester.getComponentFromLastRenderedPage("form:name").setDefaultModelObject("foo");
wicketTester.getComponentFromLastRenderedPage("form:age").setDefaultModelObject("7");
wicketTester.executeAjaxEvent("form:ajx", "click");
```